# Replace all non ascii characters with a code

Tags: c#

Is it possible in c# string to replace all non ASCII characters with a code. I have an application that prints to Zebra label printer with ZPL. It needs all UTF-8 characters to a code with leading underscore. For example if the user wants to print µ (micro symbol) I have to do

```
text = text.replace("µ", "_c2_b5");  //c2b5 is the UTF8 code for µ
```

Example "Helloµ±" should become "Hello_c2_b5_c2_b1"

Comment: What would you do for `_` itself?

Comment: Probably all characters can be replaced with underscore-UTF8 representation, not just the non-ASCII once. Underscore character therefore can be represented as _5f.

Comment: Underscore should be replaced with _5f as @Dialecticus said.

Comment: Please put that in the question then - anyone wanting to help shouldn't have to read through the comments in order to understand the requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help:

```
var source =  "Helloµ±";
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char c in source)
{
    if (c == '_')
    {
        // special case: Replace _ With _5f
        sb.Append("_5f");
    }
    else if (c < 32 || c > 127)
    {
        // handle non-ascii by using hex representation of bytes
        // TODO: check whether "surrogate pairs" are handled correctly (if required)
        var ba = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(new[] { c });
        foreach (byte b in ba)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("_{0:x2}", b);
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        // in printable ASCII range, so just copy
        sb.Append(c);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

This results in `"Hello_c2_b5_c2_b1"`

It is up to you to wrap this in a nice method.

---

Late addition: The first two tests can be combined, as `_` just has to be replaced by its byte representation, to avoid confusion about what an _ means in the result:

```
if (c == '_' || c < 32 || c > 127)
{
    var ba = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(new[] { c });
    foreach (byte b in ba)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("_{0:x2}", b);
    }
}
else
{
    sb.Append(c);
}
```

Comment: Underscore should be replaced with _5f

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

```
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("søme string");
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: That's definitely not going to do what the OP wants.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the example where it replaces all non-ascii character code from a string:

```
string s = "søme string";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", string.Empty);
```

Comment: But the OP doesn't want to remove those chars, but replace with their utf8 bytes in hex format

Comment: Here in my equation replace string.empty with the their utf8 bytes in hex format.

Comment: @HarshilKansagara: Until you've shown the code to do that, this really doesn't answer the question.